# What should be the format for the following ldap workerid?

Tags: ldap

I am trying to use the following code to get the email address from LDAP active directory? What should be the format of workerid? Should it be domainname\userid or just Environment.Username only?
I am thinking of using

```
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(entry);

            search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + workerID + ")";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sAMAccountName` attribute will usually reflect a combination of the first initial and last name of the user.

Being Greg Stachurski, my sAMAccountName in active directory is `GStachurski`.

Also, you should check out Softerra's LDAP Browser (the free version of LDAP Administrator). It's a fantastic piece of software that will be invaluable as you build applications around the LDAP protocol.

You can download it here - http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm

Comment: It turns out, you just use your msid(no domain in front). Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard SAMAccountName format.  It would be unique to your Directory Environment.  If your on a windows machine, I would recommend using the LDP.exe utility.  Select run from the start menu and enter ldp.exe (also works from the commandline).  Most windows computers should have that utility installed.  Select Connect from the Connection Menu and enter your AD server IP or FQDN and LDAP port.  Then from the Connection Menu, select Bind, enter your username and password if required (or leave blank if not required).  Then from the View Menu item, select Tree and enter the BaseDN value, you can also check the drop down for preloaded values.  From here you can expand and navigate through your directory.  Check a few user accounts to see how they have the SAMAccountName value formatted and you can base your code off that.  Hope this helps.